# Whats wrong with my code which should delete all rows where the ID is not in an array?

Tags: php

I am trying to delete all rows from a mysql database where the ID is not in my array. So I tried:

```
@mysql_query("DELETE FROM something WHERE NUMBER NOT IN (".implode(",", $array).")");
```

Somehow this doesnt do anything, is there a mistake I am not seeing?

Thanks for help!
phpheini

Comment: It will throw error when the `$array` is empty. Otherwise looks fine. Also is the field `NUMBER` valid ?? or is it `number` ?

Comment: The array aint empty and the field is really NUMBER. Hm, thats weird...

Comment: Should it be `ID` and not `NUMBER`?

Comment: Nevermind...  what happens when you echo out the query before running it (ie. `$query="DELETE FROM something WHERE NUMBER NOT IN (".implode(",", $array).")";`)

Comment: did u try this: `@mysql_query("DELETE FROM something WHERE NUMBER NOT IN ('.implode(',', $array).')");`

Comment: Do some debugging. Print the query before executing it. Remove the `@` to see errors. Use [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/mysql_error) to retrieve MySQL errors.

Comment: This has removed all the entries except the one with ID 0.
@TimWithers I will try your idea now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you don't have any issue with the given code.

Put this before the sql execution.

```
echo "DELETE FROM something WHERE NUMBER NOT IN (".implode(",", $array).")";
```

As an example it will looks like..

```
DELETE FROM something WHERE NUMBER NOT IN (1,2)
```

And get the output. Then check it with mysql client. I think you don't have any data to be deleted based on your query. Or there may be issues with relationships, foreign key, etc. However you can get exact issue if you try the query on mysql client tool.

Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

the query could return an error if $array is empty or contains non-numeric values.

check if you get an error like so:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```